# Hackerrank New Year Chaos - Ruby - Print as return

Tags: ruby

I am trying to solve [HackerRank's 'New year Chaos' challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/new-year-chaos/problem).
The script is supposed to print 'Too chaotic' in a certain case.
Regardless of wether or not my solution is correct, my current problem is that I can't seem to print it as it will then return nil. My solution is not accepted either it I replace it with a puts as it will include quotes.

```
bribes = 0
chaotic = false

  q.each_with_index do |num, index|
    if num - 1 - index > 2
      chaotic = true
    elsif index == 0
    else
      bribes += q.slice(0, index).count { |x| x > num }
    end
  end

  return chaotic ? print('Too chaotic') : bribes
end
```

[Hacker rank output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnkMJ.png)

thanks!

Comment: `nil` and quotes suggest you do something like `puts foo.inspect` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem to tackle.  The main difference between print and puts is the included newline with puts.  You want to use puts in this case.  Here's a good discussion on the topic: https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/puts-vs-print/

I'm not sure what was happening with the quotes you mention, so I'd update your solution with puts, and tackle the quotes next.